# Evaluate an expression at a specific point

Tags: evaluation

In Maple, you right click and can evaluate an expression (whatever it is) at a specific point say:

Expr.= abcddafjosjfoj, then right click and simply evaluate at c=-34 say. But how does one do the correspoinding operation in Mathematica? Must one define a function first for this simple task?

[image]

Comment: Right click and then evaluate c=-34? Huh, because c is present in `abcddafjosjfoj`? What do you mean? If there were spaces between the characters here, you could use the menu item evaluate in place.

Comment: Yes exactly you right click whatever expression you like and evaluate at whatever you like. So my question is how to do that in Mathematica?

Comment: For instance if I have an expression called E so that 
E=a*b*c*d*e...*f, then I right click on it and evaluate at point c=-34 so that E becomes
E=-34*a*b*d*...*f. Nice and simple, but what is the corr. operation in Mathematica?

Comment: I added an image - is this what you're describing?

Comment: Yes exactly cormullion. Great job!

Comment: @mapel Why don't you register your account so that  when gaining reputation you'll be able to benefit more of using this site.

Comment: You're absolutely right Artes, I should do that. I just have to come up with a good user name :)

Comment: @Artes Artes you seems to be a veteran here, and I would like to ask for an advice from you. Would you suggest one making an account with ones real name or use a pseudonym? I know it's a hard question with a lot of pros and cons but I just had to ask. I don't know if Artes is your real name but if it is (or not) do you regret you chose it (did not choose it) as your username?

Comment: @mapel It' s an individual issue, some of the most proficient users use their real names while others use nicknames, there is no obligation for using real names, but on the onther hand those using real names are perhaps considered more serious men. Another thing is that you can change your nickname (once a month if I'm not wrong).

Comment: OK thanks for you input.

Comment: @mapel I think using a real name it would be a good idea, but you can write your real name in the profile as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Mathematica this can be done any number of different ways, but the spirit of your question suggests replacement rules as the solution you're looking for.

Consider x (a delayed expession; will re-evaluate RHS each time 'x' is evaluated)

```
x := 4*c^2
```

Now use ReplaceAll (shorthand notation is /.) and a Rule (shorthand notation is ->)

```
x /. c -> 2.5

(*25.*)
```

Note you can also try a number of these at once:

```
x /. c -> {2.5, 3, 8}

(*{25., 36, 256}*)
```

See the docs on ReplaceAll and Rule for more examples. An alternative approach would be to define a function and pass values explicitly.

Comment: I think you nailed it bro. I'll try it out and comment soon.